# String between to strings regex expression

Tags: java, regex, soap

So i have the following string:

```
    <GetMyeBaySellingResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


<Timestamp>2016-06-03T08:56:30.123Z</Timestamp>

<....>
<.....>
</GetMyeBaySellingResponse>
```

i would like to have a regex that will extract the ..... in between the main problem is that

sometimes arrive as

```
<GetMyeBaySellingResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
```

so i need something that looking for a beginning of  `<GetMyeBaySellingResponse`  and the first `>` as a prefix

So i need a matcher that `(start with  <GetMyeBaySellingResponse and end with the first >) and (end with <GetMyeBaySellingResponse/>)`

Comment: And do you really need to regex for this? I think so much better option is using Parser to get inner part of xml. Then you have to only fill first element as path to xPath and you are able to get it all. If you want, I can show you working code example for parsing xml and get inner part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regular expression.

```
/<GetMyeBaySellingResponse[^>]*>(?:([^<]*)<GetMyeBaySellingResponse\/>)?/
```

Group 1 will contain the string if there is any.

---

**Updated for the rephrased question.** The expression above does not work on the updated text in the question. Try the following regular expression to match any text within the `GetMyeBaySellingResponse` including any XML elements.

```
/<GetMyeBaySellingResponse[^>]*>(?:((?:(?!<\/GetMyeBaySellingResponse>)(?:.|\s))*)<\/GetMyeBaySellingResponse>)?/
```

Comment: its only match in case the text ... is in the same line, but i have multiple lines in the ....  how can we fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:[\n]*(?:(?:<.+>)(.*)(?:<.+>)))\n*
```

https://regex101.com/r/vK4fY6/3

Comment: its only match in case the text ... is in the same line, but i have multiple lines in the ....  how can we fix it?

Comment: @User Updated with what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think this simple code would do the job.

```
<GetMyeBaySellingResponse [\S\s]*<\/GetMyeBaySellingResponse>
```